# can anyone help me? i want to display those data label Permanently in graph on their position

Tags: javascript, html, css, pie-chart

i want to display those data label Permanently in graph on their position.so that it always visible, not only when i hover those. Can anyone help me with it?[Here is the example ,like this one] i also dropped my code.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY8X1.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <title>Pie Chart Example</title> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div style="position: relative;"> 
<canvas id="pieChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
</div>

<script> 
// Get the canvas element var canvas = document.getElementById('pieChart');
// Create the pie chart
var pieChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['Online', 'Offline'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [8, 2],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(71, 190, 125, 1)', 'rgba(241, 65, 108, 1)'],
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        anchor: 'end', // Position of the data labels (start, center, end)
        align: 'end', // Text alignment (start, center, end)
        offset: 10,   // Offset of the label from the chart
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          let label = ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
          return label + ': ' + value + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>   
</body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a separate  container for the labels and styled them to match the chart colors. I'm using flexbox to position the labels on the left side of the chart. The positionLabelsContainer() function positions the labels container based on the chart size, and I've added an event listener to reposition it on window resize.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pie Chart Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <canvas id="pieChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <div id="labels-container" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;">
                <div style="background-color: rgba(71, 190, 125, 1); width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;"></div>
                <div style="background-color: rgba(241, 65, 108, 1); width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start; margin-left: 5px;">
                <div>Online: 8%</div>
                <div>Offline: 2%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Get the canvas element
        var canvas = document.getElementById('pieChart');
        var labelsContainer = document.getElementById('labels-container');
        
        // Create the pie chart
        var pieChart = new Chart(canvas, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: ['Online', 'Offline'],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [8, 2],
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(71, 190, 125, 1)', 'rgba(241, 65, 108, 1)'],
                    borderWidth: 0
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    datalabels: false // Disable datalabels as they're displayed in the custom container
                }
            }
        });
        
        // Position the labels container according to the chart size
        function positionLabelsContainer() {
            labelsContainer.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
            labelsContainer.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
        }

        positionLabelsContainer(); // Initial positioning

        window.addEventListener('resize', positionLabelsContainer); // Update on resize
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you change the only percent number in the middle of their chart to look like this? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY8X1.png